# How to run Java Applet in browser without activating plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, applet

I know this may sound like a silly question, but I was wondering if there was a way to run Java Applets on my server and embed them to a page in a way that the user would not have to "allow access" to the applet, because it wouldn't have direct connection with their computer. In other words, make an embedded java applet which wouldn't download to the client side? I understand that the lifetime of an applet is only in the web browser when a user activates a plugin and all of that.. So how can I run Java APplets on my server?

Comment: You can't. This is in direct contrast to what an applet is. You can run a web application on your server and you can distribute client-side applications using Java Web Start. Applets are, by their very nature donwloaded and ran in the browser

Comment: Are you looking for AppletViewer?

Comment: So then is there any other possible way to display a java application on the browser without the user having to go through the "allowing access" stage? (Which usually drives many people away from the application)

Comment: *"So then is there any other possible way to display a java application on the browser without the user having to go through the "allowing access" stage?"*  Sure. Look to servlets and JSP.

Comment: I've looked at those, but they don't seem to be able to run a java application, just affect a static web page with java.

Comment: *"they don't seem to be able to run a java application"*  Both JSP and servlets **are a** Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically everything is possible. Applet is a special java application that extends `Applet` or `JApplet`. `Applet` just extends `Panel`. You can simulate applet container by implementing your own dummy appet context and run applet on server side.

Now, you can capture its UI and stream it to browser using AJAX or even web sockets. You can catch mouse and keyboard events in browser, send them using ajax to server where your applet is running and emulate the same events on your applets.

But may I ask you "why?" I think these efforts can be reasonable only if you have a huge applet and do not want to re-implement it using other technologies. But IMHO it is easier to re-write your applet using ExtJs or GWT. In GWT it is probably the better way because GWT is a java that is compiled to javascript, so you will probably be able to reuse most of your code.